# Magento- Custom attribute not displayed in product "Update Attributes"

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes

There's a custom attribute inserted in magento by third party extension. This attribute is not listed among other attributes on `Catalog > Manage Products > Actions > Update Attributes`.

Are there any requirements in order an attribute to be able to edited massively on products?

Comment: Please check its website scope. it is global or website or store level, and if possible could you please share it setup file to check attributes properties so i can give you that solution

Comment: I think that you need to go to stores->attributes sets, open it fo edit and just add it, press save.

Comment: @alexeyboltynov attribute is already added to attribute set

Comment: @HiteshAgrawal attribute is already Global

Comment: @zekia , Could you please share data upgrade file.